# ExtJS 5 - How do I pass parameter to store in expanded row?

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I'm looking at the example on this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/k8q) of rowexapnder and it shows how to nest grids using row exapnder.

I want to get different data per row which means sending id parameter to the nested row.

this is the code of the nested row :

how can I add the **id** to the **personStore** so each exapnded show will have different data (and not the same data as in the fiddle)

```js
exapndInnerGrid : function(record) {
                var id = record.get('id');
                var row = Ext.get('empDivId-' + record.get('name'));
                if (!row.dom.childNodes.length) {
                    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
                        store: personStore,
                        plugins: {
                            ptype: 'cellediting',
                            clicksToEdit: 1
                        },
                        columns: [{
                            text: 'WorkName',
                            dataIndex: 'workName',
                            locked: true
                        }, {
                            text: 'Designation',
                            dataIndex: 'designation'
                        }, {
                            text: 'Salary',
                            dataIndex: 'salary',
                            editor: {
                                xtype: 'numberfield',
                                allowBlank: false,
                                minValue: 0,
                                maxValue: 100000
                            }
                        }, {
                            text: 'Gender',
                            dataIndex: 'gender',
                            lockable: false
                        }],
                        height: 150,
                        width: 400,
                        renderTo: row
                    });   
                }
                
            }
```

Comment: You need to load the personStore each time by passing id as an extraparam for the store. You can manually load it with the corresponding id when you expand the rowexpander

Comment: but I can't load it each time because the store run once for all the nested grid

Comment: So how is the data for the inner grid dependent on the selected id? Some example?

Comment: Another way is to filter the store when on expand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some like this - [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/lfq) (I've modified the fiddle that you provided with some changes)
    If the personStore is already loaded then apply filter whenever you expand for a row and then create a temporary store and add the filtered records to that store and use the temp store for the inner grid.

```
    exapndInnerGrid : function(record) {
        var row = Ext.get('empDivId-' + record.get('name'));
        var name = record.get('name');
        if (!row.dom.childNodes.length) {
            //personStore.clearFilter();
            personStore.filter('workName', name);
            var personStore2 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                fields: [{
                    name: 'workName'
                }, {
                    name: 'designation'
                }, {
                    name: 'salary'
                }, {
                    name: 'gender'
                }]
            });
            personStore2.add(personStore.getRange());
            Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
                store: personStore2,
                plugins: {
                    ptype: 'cellediting',
                    clicksToEdit: 1
                },
                columns: [{
                    text: 'WorkName',
                    dataIndex: 'workName',
                    locked: true
                }, {
                    text: 'Designation',
                    dataIndex: 'designation'
                }, {
                    text: 'Salary',
                    dataIndex: 'salary',
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'numberfield',
                        allowBlank: false,
                        minValue: 0,
                        maxValue: 100000
                    }
                }, {
                    text: 'Gender',
                    dataIndex: 'gender',
                    lockable: false
                }],
                height: 150,
                width: 400,
                renderTo: row
            });   
        }

    }
```

Comment: I've already found a solution , little bit "classier" than yours , but you were on the right track.

personStore.clearFilter();   
personStore.filter('workName',record.get('name'));

Just added these two rows after creating the grid.

Comment: That's good :) . Do check the inner grids by expanding them all.

Comment: lol... you are right man , my solution delete rest of the inner grids ... you da man ! :)

Comment: May I send you personal email ?

Comment: That's why the second store. :) Surely, you can send personal email.

Comment: I don't know your address .

Comment: you can send to yellenseram@gmail.com